# Prevent contentSizeForViewInPopover from animating

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a popover which contains a `UITableView`.  In the storyboard I've set the popover height to fit the entire table, and it displays nicely.  However, in some situations I need to display less cells, and in these cases I'd like to change the height of the popover.  I do it thus:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 
    if (trimFourCells) {  // reduce the popover's height by that of four cells
        CGSize size = self.contentSizeForViewInPopover;
        size.height -= 4*60;
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = size;
    }
}
```

It works well, except that the change is animated: first the full size is shown, then it shrink in about one second.

My question is whether this animation can be disabled.

I have tried to pass `NO` in `[super viewDidAppear:animated]`, and even tried to move that line after the size change.  It did not prevent the animation.  Then I tried to move the code to `viewWillAppear`, and that did not even change the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @frowing, here is the solution.  Instead of changing the size in the popover's code, it has to be done in the caller.  I have added code like the following to `prepareForSegue`:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIPopoverController *pc = ((UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue).popoverController;
    if (trim_nCells > 0) { // trim that many cells from the table
        CGSize size = pc.contentViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover;
        size.height -= trim_nCells * cellHeight;
        [pc setPopoverContentSize:size animated:NO];
    }
    (... rest of the prep code ...)
}
```

Note that since it's done before the display, there is no animation involved, so the value of the `animated:` param has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
- (void)setPopoverContentSize:(CGSize)size animated:(BOOL)animated
```

like this:

```
[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:size animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks, @frowing.  This solved the problem, but introduce a new problem, of flicker.  The popover appears full size, then a split second later it resizes.  I tried to fix this by moving the `[super viewDidAppear:animated]` line after the resizing, but it did not help.

I assume that by the time `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` is called, the popup is already displayed full size, so any resizing must be done beforehand.

Comment: Set the content size before showing the popover. Remove the resizing code from the `viewDidAppear:` method.

Comment: Thanks, @frowing. I moved the code from `viewDidAppear:` to `viewWillAppear:`. I tried to put it before the `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` line and then after the line. In both cases no resizing happened at all. It seems that `setPopoverContentSize:(CGSize)size animated:(BOOL)animated`
has no effect when called inside `viewWillAppear:`. Likewise, setting controller's the size directly in `viewWillAppear:` as in `ctrl.popoverContentSize = size;` has no effect. Surely I'm missing something, because I can't find any way to resize before the popover is shown. I can only resize after.

Comment: Just to clarify, `setPopoverContentSize:animated:` should be called from outside the popoverController. Ideally right before presenting it. Post some code showing how you create the popover, and where exactly you are calling `setPopoverContentSize:animated:`