# Prevent animation when dynamically resizing popover

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

So I realized this myself and found this answer to confirm:

[Prevent contentSizeForViewInPopover from animating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528907/prevent-contentsizeforviewinpopover-from-animating)

Basically I am in a similar boat in that I want to dynamically resize my popover, depending on how much data I have to display. I am also getting this animation action where the popover view moves into place. The problem is, I can't set the popover's content size in the caller/parent, because neither the size of the content view for the text view nor the frame for the text view in my popover is known until viewDidAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews is called, but of course at this point it's too late, the popover is already on its way to being visible, thus I am getting this unwanted animation.

I am dynamically setting the size of the text views in the popover view controller class to fit the amount of data the text views are displaying, and this only works at the point where their frame size is defined/known/however you want to word it when it hasn't gotten to that point yet in the view lifecycle.

I should mention that I have my view controllers and view all done in a storyboard.

Does this make sense? Hope I'm explaining it well. Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

EDIT Here is my viewDidLayoutSubviews method from the view controller I am loading in the popover - hopefully this makes it clear. The first time this loads, if I don't do this in viewDidLayoutSubviews or viewDidAppear the frame for my 2 text views are CGRectZero, the text views don't resize for the content correctly and the popover size isn't right either:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

self.physicianDataNewValueTextView.text = self.physicianDataNewValue;
CGRect frame = self.physicianDataNewValueTextView.frame;
frame.size.height = self.physicianDataNewValueTextView.contentSize.height;
self.physicianDataNewValueTextView.frame = frame;

self.physicianDataOldValueTextView.text = self.physicianDataOldValue;
frame = self.physicianDataOldValueTextView.frame;
frame.size.height = self.physicianDataOldValueTextView.contentSize.height;
self.physicianDataOldValueTextView.frame = frame;

self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(384.0f, self.physicianDataOldValueTextView.frame.size.height + 75.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I decided to use delegation. Instead of resetting the content size in the view controller for the popover, I call my delegate (which is the containing view controller) with the new size so I can set it there with the animated property set to NO. Works well.

Comment: Great help, thanks! The code I've used in my delegate method is: `[self.chooseEquipmentPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:size animated:NO];`

Comment: Glad this posting helped. If you wouldn't mind voting my answer up that would be great, thanks (unless you already did).